# Transaction reverted when testing requires/asserts in non void functions

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

im trying to test the requires of a Smart Contract using just solidity according to this article:

http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/testing-for-throws-in-solidity-tests

This is the contract, the throw proxy contract and the test:

```
/* Testing with solidity tests. */

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/MyContract.sol";

contract TestMyContract {

function testInitialStoredValue() {
    MyContract mycontract = new MyContract();

    uint expected = 24;

    Assert.equal(mycontract.mynumber(), expected, "First number set should be 24.");
}

function testTheThrow() {
    MyContract mycontract = new MyContract(); 

    ThrowProxy throwproxy = new ThrowProxy(address(mycontract)); 
    uint num = 7;
    MyContract(address(throwproxy)).storeNum(num);

    bool r = throwproxy.execute.gas(200000)(); 

    Assert.isFalse(r, "Should be false because is should throw!");

}

function testNoThrow() {
    MyContract mycontract = new MyContract(); 

    ThrowProxy throwproxy = new ThrowProxy(address(mycontract)); 

    MyContract(address(throwproxy)).storeNum(22);

    bool r = throwproxy.execute.gas(200000)(); 

    Assert.isTrue(r, "Should be true because is should throw!");

}

}

// Proxy contract for testing throws
contract ThrowProxy {
  address public target;
  bytes data;

  function ThrowProxy(address _target) {
    target = _target;
  }

  //prime the data using the fallback function.
  function() {
    data = msg.data;
  }

  function execute() returns (bool) {
    return target.call(data);
  }
}
```

If i run the tests i get this error:

[image: 2]

If i change the storeNum function to void from

```
 function storeNum(uint mynum)
        public
        returns (bool success)
    {
     require(mynum > 10);
     mynumber = mynum; 
     return true;    
    }
```

to

```
 function storeNum(uint mynum)
        public
    {
     require(mynum > 10);
     mynumber = mynum; 
     return true;    
    }
```

the tests works..

Any ideas?

Im using Truffle v4.1.11

**EDIT:**

I have submited an issue in truffle github, maybe the recent changes on solidity has this constraint or breaks the test using a proxy

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1001

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 function storeNum(uint mynum)
    public
    returns (bool success)
{
 require(mynum > 10);
 mynumber = mynum; 
 return true;    
}
```

Try removing `success` as a return variable since you are not returning that specific variable:

```
 function storeNum(uint mynum)
    public
    returns (bool)
{
 require(mynum > 10);
 mynumber = mynum; 
 return true;    
}
```

If you wanted to keep `returns (bool success)` you could do something like this:

```
 function storeNum(uint mynum)
   public
   returns (bool success)
 {
   require(mynum > 10);
   mynumber = mynum; 
   success = true;    
 }
```

Comment: Hi, i understand, but that isnt seems to be the cause of the problem, im getting the same error. Not only with boolean values, also with numeric. I have submited an issue into truffle an edited the question